# Unable to set luminosty with a usb boot

Tags: boot, live-usb

When I boot from a live USB I can't adjust luminosity.

I need to plug a VGA screen to my laptop in order to be able to see the screen.

I managed to fix that when I installed Ubuntu with the following lines :

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Then changing the value of this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

But now that I am trying to boot from live USB, changing the grub splash won't be a solution.

Any clue on how to fix this and why it happens mostly in all Linux distros on my laptop ?